# How do I use the strconv.Atoi() method in Go?

Tags: input, go, casting

I am trying to get a user input in this small program. I have tried doing this several ways with the `strconv.Atoi()` method (my input is obviously a string, and I'm trying to convert it to an integer). Here's my first attempt:

```
package main
    import (
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
    )
    
    func main() {
        //fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa)
        fmt.Println("Say something, in numbers.")
        var inputstr string
        fmt.Scanln("%s", &inputstr)
        input := strconv.Atoi(inputstr)
        output := (input * 2)
        outputstr := strconv.Itoa(output)
        fmt.Println(outputstr)
    }
```

and got the following error when it came to compiling:

> (line 19) multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in single-value context

I then looked into Godocs and tried to figure this out for myself, and then realized that an error value is returned as well. So, I changed the

```
input := strconv.Atoi(inputstr)
```

to

```
input, _ := strconv.Atoi(inputstr)
```

Now this compiles just fine, without any errors. However, when I run the program, here's what I get:

> Say something, in numbers.
>
> 0

and then it exits... What am I doing wrong? I believe this is a question about to `Atoi()` method, but if it's concerning the `Scanln()` then please correct me.

Comment: You should *deal* with your errors, rather than just ignoring them. They may help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: You are absolutely right. What I'm doing here is bad programming, but more than anything I need an explanation on how things work. So, I go here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem turns out to be the Scanln.  Scanln is returning an error `type not a pointer` because of the %s. This then leaves inputstr blank, which when given to Atoi is returning an error: `strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax`.

Using Scanf as follows with no change to the Atoi:

```
func main() {
    //fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa)
    fmt.Println("Say something, in numbers.")
    var inputstr string

    //fmt.Scanln("%s", &inputstr)
    _, err := fmt.Scanf("%s", &inputstr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    input, e := strconv.Atoi(inputstr)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
    output := (input * 2)
    outputstr := strconv.Itoa(output)
    fmt.Println(outputstr)
}
```

Probably the simplest solution is to remove the "%s" from the Scanln.

Comment: So basically, the "%s" is just a format character that converts the input to a string?

Comment: Actually, the %s is used as a format character for Sscan, but in your code its getting two errors one from the `Scanf("%s",..)` not liking the %s and the next from `Atoi` not liking an empty string.